# Using sed or awk or a tool from a fresh Debian 9 install, how to do text appending untrimmed?

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk, sed

How can I with sed or awk or a tool present in fresh debian 9 install, do the following text appending:

```
sed '/"start":/a     "start:prod": "hello",' package.json
```

Currently my string starting spaces are trimmed

This is what we have  :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export REACT_APP_ENV=${REACT_APP_ENV:-default} && cp src/env/.env.$REACT_APP_ENV .env && react-scripts start",
```

"start:prod": "hello",
        ...
      },

This is what we expect  :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export REACT_APP_ENV=${REACT_APP_ENV:-default} && cp src/env/.env.$REACT_APP_ENV .env && react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "hello",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Show us the package.json and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\` after `a` command (assuming `GNU sed` from `linux` tag)

```
$ seq 3 | sed '/2/a foobaz'
1
2
foobaz
3
$ seq 3 | sed '/2/a\ foobaz'
1
2
 foobaz
3
```

From [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands)

> Leading whitespace after the a command is ignored
>
> Escape sequences in text are processed, so you should use `\\` in text to print a single backslash

Alternate way is to use `r` command

```
$ seq 3 > ip.txt
$ # need to take care of escape sequences, unless that is a feature you need
$ sed '/2/a\ a\\ny' ip.txt
1
2
 a\ny
3

$ # r command will add the text as is
$ # won't cause trouble for multiline text, clashes with sed meta characters, etc
$ echo ' a\ny' | sed '/2/r /dev/stdin' ip.txt
1
2
 a\ny
3
$ # or from file input
$ echo ' a\ny' > f1
$ sed '/2/r f1' ip.txt
1
2
 a\ny
3
```

or, use the substitute command to capture blanks at start of line and reuse for appending

```
$ echo '  hello123' | sed -E 's/^([[:blank:]]+)hello.*/&\n\1hi/'
  hello123
  hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this:-

```
sed -e "/\"start\":/a\\
      \"start:prod\": \"hello\"," <  package.json
```

But please keep in mind there must be two lines of script like above. Do not make it a single line. It will output

```
"scripts": {
"start": "export REACT_APP_ENV=${REACT_APP_ENV:-default} && cp src/env/.env.$REACT_APP_ENV .env && react-scripts start",
"start:prod": "hello",
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for s/old/new/ **that is all**. Just use awk:

```
awk '{print} sub(/"start":.*/,""){print $0 "\"start:prod\": \"hello\","}' package.json
```

Note that the above will simply print the new line with the same indentation as the previous line using whatever combination of blanks and/or tabs are present in the input, you don't need to hard-code leading spaces that you hope will match the original.